# Do random events really exist?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, determinism, randomness

To highly clarify my question, let me define what I mean by a random event: "the event *e* is random, if and only if by having all the data about an event *e*, we cannot predict the consequences of the event *e*"

e.g. according to this definition, computers don't generate numbers really random. They just get a seed that is the current milisecond that we're living in, and the function `rand` generates a number between 0 and 1 according to the seed, and it won't generate another number if we don't change the seed - by having enough data, i.e. the current milisecond and the way that the function `rand` is implemented, we can be sure that what number the function `rand` is going to generate, without even executing the function, therefore it's not really random

In my view, random events cannot exist:

Assuming the event *e* is functioned by the function $f$, and the value $D$ is all the data related to the event *e*, if the event *e* is random, the function $f$ should return different values (with its parameter $D$) such as $a$ and $b$, in case that $a \neq b$. That shows us something is causing the function $f$ to return multiple values - call that cause the value $E$ - and now, $f(D \cup E)$ shouldn't return both values $a$ and $b$, since we passed the reason that it caused it to return both $a$ and $b$, as the function's parameter, and since it returns only one value now, it's no longer random

Wanted to know that, do you agree with that? And do you think that random events exist (in quantum physics or whatever)?

Comment: The culprit is the assumption that you can *know* whether or not you have "all the data" related to an event or not. In physics there have been some attempts to rule out what is called "hidden variable theories" of QM, this may relate to your question... as far as I know no one can rule out such theories completely without bringing in some other assumptions

Comment: Another false assumption of yours is that classical physical events exist. That it just an old approximation that does not work as soon as we are looking at microscopic systems.

Comment: In short, [Bell test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_test) in quantum mechanics has shown that no "hidden local variable" can explain or predict exact quantum outcome/event. By your terms this means, that there is no such $E$, so that $$f: D \cup E \rightarrow \{ a \} \tag 1$$

Hence quantum mechanical events are truly random, because they can only be described probabilistically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even the equations of quantum mechanics are deterministic functions.  However, there's a catch.  It is currently believed that there is no way to *observe* the complete quantum mechanical state of the system.  We do not believe there to be any means to do so.  Thus we must always make our predictions on incomplete information.

To go beyond that dabbles into the realm of philosophy.  If we include knowing all information about event e, then by definition we know all information about e.  So for any event e, there *is* some information we can define which, if we knew it, we would know everything about e.  But such tautological nonsense is not really what you're asking for -- its just a useful bound to the question.  It points out that the specific nuances of how you define "all the data about e" will affect the answer.  Typically we rephrase this as "all of the data available *before* e," and then ask about the data following e.  And then we have to quibble about "available."  If we phrase that as "all the information *knowable* before e," then it is currently believed that we cannot know enough to predict e with complete certainty.  The best we can do is probabalistic bounds.